# Access iCloud Music Library download and iCloud status programmatically

Tags: ios, mpmediaitem, itunes-sdk

Can the `iCloud download status` be accessed programmatically from the `MPMediaLibrary - MPMediaItemProperty` or other source?

We want to detect the source of a song so we know if it is from Apple Music (DRM), matched using `iTunes Match` (not DRM), purchased, or simply uploaded from a ripped CD etc.

The document [About iCloud Music Library icons and status](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203564) describes the download icon and status for files in the `Media Library`, and see them in iTunes on the Mac, but can't find a way to get this status information within the app.

Comment: It looks like this may be accessible from the iTunes Music Library.xml. Find `<key>Playlists</key>`, and below that will be assigned IDs for each track. Then find `<key>Name</key><string>Downloaded</string>`. Below that there are the IDs of each downloaded track.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this? My search turned nothing. I'm considering opening an API request to get this info.

Comment: No, we haven't found how to do this yet.

Comment: If you just want to check if the song is DRM-protected or not, you can use the MPMediaItem's hasProtectedAsset property.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MPMediaItem` properties - `isCloudItem` to check download status and `hasProtectedAsset` to check DRM protection.

[See MPMediaItem docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaitem)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).